# Put a complete dom in a variable and remove element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div inside a div:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    <div id="to_delete">
      [changing content]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to keep this visible on my page just like it is. But I'm sending the the content from #foo to the server with ajax (which works just fine).

What I don't want to send from that content is:

```
<div id="to_delete">
  [changing content]
</div>
```

That needs to be filtered out before sending. So I need a way to put a complete DOM in a variable, edit that variable and then send it.

For this to happen I used remove() and parseHtml() which is not doing what it needs to do.

My current solution is (the one that doesn't work):

```
// put html in a variable as a string
var html = $('#foo').html();

// remove from parsed html and return a string which is ready to be sent
var htmlParsed = $.parseHTML(html).remove('#to_delete').html();  

// send htmlParsed (this part needs no code)
```

Any help is as always appreciated

Comment: why not clone the #foo and then use the `remove()` normally

Comment: also note that `$.parseHTML` returns an array of DOM elements, so you should have used `$($.parseHTML(html)[0]).remove(...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `#to_delete` is not one of the selected elements, `remove(<selector>)` does not work here. I would clone the node, remove the element and then convert it to HTML:

```
var clone = $('#foo').clone();
clone.find('#to_delete').remove();
var html = clone.html();
```

Comment: clone... Darn, that was simpler than mine in a mile. I tested it and it works like it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the the html that you don't want then copy the rest of the html and then again insert the removed html.

```
function test(){
            var deletedHtml = $('#to_delete').html(), serverHtml;
            $('#to_delete').remove();
            serverHtml = $('body').html();
            $('#bar').html(deletedHtml);
            console.log(serverHtml);
        }
```